# Optimize the lowest size of sub lists

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

I am working with a problem. The core of problem is shown as below. Does anyone have idea get the lowest size?

Given an n*m list, where each element is either 0 or 1. We need to select a subset of elements from each list (represented as x) out of the n lists to form a new list and add it to set A (where identical lists are stored only once, without duplicates). The remaining elements in x will form a new list, which is added to another list B (where duplicates are allowed). The goal is to design an algorithm that minimizes the total number of bits in set A and the number of bits in list B ?

Lowest Size of (size(A)+size(B))